# SQL IF skipping next IF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, union

I am trying to run an SQL full of created tables, but only create the tables that are called. For example when W comes in, I want just the W table to be displayed. Same if just S comes in. But if it comes in as 'W,S' I want both tables to be created and then union'd together. (sorry if I cant explain it good >_>) Here is what I have so far:

```
Declare @dept varchar = 'W,S'
Declare @tempW Table (Code int)
Declare @tempS Table (Code int)
Declare @num int

IF @dept LIKE '%W%'
        SET @num = 0
        While (@num <= 499)
        Begin
            Insert Into @tempW (Code)
            Values(@num)
            SET @num += 1
        END

IF @dept LIKE '%S%'
        SET @num = 500
        While (@num <= 599)
        Begin
            Insert Into @tempS (Code)
            Values(@num)
            SET @num += 1
        END

Select
    Code
From
    @tempW

UNION ALL

Select
    Code
From
    @tempS
```

So basically W table will be filled with numbers 0-499 and S will be filled with 500-599. But the problem is, if just S or W gets passed, it works fine. But when 'W,S' gets passed, it populates the W table and then skips over the S table and just displays the W table.

Anyone know whats on the go here?

Comment: You're not using `begin` and `end` on your `if` statements... is that intentional? As a result, your loops will always run. Your `set` statements are the only lines affected by the if statement.

Comment: Why the While Statements?  Since you set Num right before using it the While, it will always be true, so get rid of them!

Comment: The while statement is because i want table W to be filled with numbers 0-499 so i set the num to 0 before the loop begins. Same with the S table, I want the numbers 500-599 in the S table so i set the num to 500 before the loop begins.

Comment: Your issue is that you declared `@dept` as `varchar` without a precision... so your string gets truncated to `W` and your second `if` condition is never met. See my edit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887115/621962).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `begin` and `end` on your `if` statements. As a result, your `set` statements are the only lines affected by the `if`. Your loops always run.

```
IF @dept LIKE '%W%' begin -- encapsulate several statements
     SET @num = 0
     While (@num <= 499) Begin
         Insert Into @tempW (Code)
         Values(@num)
         SET @num += 1
     END
end

IF @dept LIKE '%S%' begin -- encapsulate several statements
    SET @num = 500
    While (@num <= 599) Begin
        Insert Into @tempS (Code) Values(@num)
        SET @num += 1
    END
end
```

**EDIT** Also, more importantly, you declared `@dept` as `varchar` **without specifying length**. By default, string length is `1`. So, it truncated your string to `"W"`... and your second `if` condition was never met.

```
declare @dept varchar(50) = 'W,S'
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13489).

Comment: See my comment on the above answer, adding the `BEGIN` and `END` to the IF statements does nothing to the result.

Comment: YES! I tried adding a length to the Varchar and it seemed to be working for a while. But if just W is added to the String it reads both IF statements as true, displaying both tables.

Comment: Never mind, I had the Begin/End statements in the wrong place. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some BEGIN and END statements from your IFs:

```
    IF @dept LIKE '%W%'
    BEGIN
     SET @num = 0
     While (@num <= 499)
     Begin
        Insert Into @tempWine (Code)
        Values(@num)
        SET @num += 1
     END
    END

    IF @dept LIKE '%S%'
    BEGIN
     SET @num = 500
     While (@num <= 599)
     Begin
        Insert Into @tempSpirit (Code)
        Values(@num)
        SET @num += 1
     END
    END
```

---

From your comment, it looks like your original problem was that you haven't declared your varchar variable with a length.  It defaults to a length of 1 char and everything else is being truncated.  Declaring it as follows makes this work:

```
Declare @dept VARCHAR(5) = 'W,S'
```

Comment: I had it like that and it did nothing to the result, still getting a return of the W table and no S table.

Comment: @Caveman42 I was assuming that this was a typo due to transcribing in here, but your union uses TempS and TempW while your inserts are into TempWine and TempSpirit, if that has any bearing.

Comment: Yes that was a typo on my part trying to move the query here. I'll fix that.